# How to add exclude negative numbers

Tags: go

> Write a program that queries the user for three positive integers and
> displays messages:
>
> 1. All numbers are equal if all three numbers are equal
> 2. Two numbers are equal if any two numbers out of three are equal
> 3. All numbers are different if all three numbers entered are different
>
> If there is an error in the input data, e.g., negative numbers are
> entered, the program should display the message Invalid Input

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a, b, c int
    fmt.Scan(&a)
    fmt.Scan(&b)
    fmt.Scan(&c)
    if (a != b && a > 0) && (b != c && c > 0) && (a != c && b > 0) {
        fmt.Print("All the numbers are different")
    } else if a == b && b == a && a == c && c == b {
        fmt.Print("All numbers are equal")
    } else if (a == b && b > 0) || (b == a && a > 0) || (c == a && a > 0) || (c == b && b > 0) {
        fmt.Print("Two numbers are equal")
    } else {
        fmt.Print("Invalid request")
    }
}
```

If I enter for example `-4 -4 -4` how can I make the program output an incorrect query?

Comment: Since having one or more negative numbers is its own condition, you should just use that as the first if block. Unrelated, equality is transitive and symmetric, ie, merely a == b && b == c already prove a, b and c are equal, and your (a == b && b > 0) and (b == a && a > 0)  are actually superfluous, you only need one of them.

Comment: @Martheen
Thank you very much. Why didn't I realize that right away)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a set. The idiomatic way to implement a set in Go is to use a map.

And than check the length of the set.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var a int = 5
    var b int = 9
    var c int = 5

    fmt.Scan(&a)
    fmt.Scan(&b)
    fmt.Scan(&c)

    s := map[int]bool{a: true, b: true, c: true}

    if a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0 {
        fmt.Print("Invalid request")
    } else if len(s) == 3 {
        fmt.Print("All the numbers are different")
    } else if len(s) == 2 {
        fmt.Print("Two numbers are equal")
    } else if len(s) == 1 {
        fmt.Print("All numbers are equal")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution

But I haven't studied "map" yet. And the assignment requires to use only if and else

Answer (score -1):

Probably involve initially reading the full input line and parsing to check conditions are what is wanted. If the line is OK parse the three numbers and perform the calculation. Otherwise put out the "Invalid request" message.

This person-machine interface kind of thing can get complicated. Perhaps mostly avoid the issue with a loop that produces and reads:
Enter first:
Enter second:
Enter third:

Another option is to produce a form that has three fields and an Enter button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).